# TensorFlow: querying session configuration

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any way to query the current configurations used by a TensorFlow session? For example

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 44
config.inter_op_parallelism_threads = 44
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

In TensorFlow (1.10 is the version I'm using) I can't seem to find a way to read back the values of the configuration in the `sess` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the "private" variable `_config` with:

```
sess._config
```

That's a class of type `tensorflow.core.protobuf.config_pb2.ConfigProto` (in short, you can access the `intra_op_parallelism_threads` and `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and any other property you added in the `tf.ConfigProto` definition).